# Dynatree jquery plugin does not show selected nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree

Got some records like:

```
{
    key: 0,
    title: "some country",
    select: true,
    childred: country state collection
}
```

Problem:

collection filed on server like: "if not all children states selected then country not selected."

Not all states inside country are selected, so when i set this "selectMode: 3" I expect country node with "dynatree-partsel" style but all nodes are unselected (country and states). If i set "selectMode: 2" - works fine: country not selected, states - selected.

How to initialize "selectMode: 3" collection with "dynatree-partsel" state?

P.S.
[Sample](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) doesn work with "selectMode: 3" either.

Comment: Make a fiddle and share the fiddle , other wise it's very difficult to understand what's  happening and hat is not

Comment: did you ever get any answers to this as i am looking in to some thing similar. I want to initialize a tree with some part selections